# PowerBuilder script

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-conversion

I'm trying to write a script which allows the tool to run only 5 times.  If the user tries to run the tool a 6th time, the tool should throw an error as Expired.

Can anyone please help me in this?

Comment: Define 'tool'  -  is this the application or some sort of control on an application?

Answer (score 1):

Create a registry key and control it that way.  HKCU\Software\YourApp\timesrun or something like that...  Increment it by one everytime the "tool" runs, and throw an exception when it exceeds 5 times.

-Paul Horan-